# A Fast Way to Color Polygon With 200 Row With Six Selected Color in QGIS 3.4.2

Tags: qgis, layers

I have a  layer of the world that contains 200 rows.

I am required to color the map with six selected colors, the rainbow colors.

[image]

I figure that I can save selected countries and save them separately.

[image]

Once they saved I can upload them and make the color ramp I needed.

[image]

However, I was wondered is there a faster way to do this without making six layers and without choosing each country manually in the Layer Styling bar panel.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following further clarification by [Nitzan Matan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25199/nitzan-matan), this is another map representation.

[image]

This categorization was made by `round((y(centroid($geometry))+80)/30)` .

To divide latitude range (`-90 ~ +80`) in this sample data from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) into 6 zones (bands), I first added 80 and divided by 30. You will need to modify these numbers according to your dataset.

[image]

Now change the color to fit with your rainbow palette.

**NB** One caveat - you will notice Alaska is green. If you want it to be like Russia and Canada, consider breaking US into parts.

Comment: Very smart!, Can you explained more about the latitude range?

Comment: @NitzanMatan Yes, more specifically the latitude ranges (-90.00000 ~ 83.64513) and found as part of `Extent` in the `Layer Properties | Information`. But I need to know only the `y-coord` of `centroid` so it does not have to be such precise.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using QGIS 3.4.2, you can use **Topological coloring** Tool, which is in the `Processing Toolbox | Cartography`.

Start this tool and give **6** (any number of colors you want to have) in the `Minimum number of colors` and hit <kbd>Run</kbd>. It will return a new layer **Colored** with an additional integer field `color_id`.

So the last step is to open the Layer Property of this layer and set `Categorized` color scheme on the `color_id` column (field). You then change each of these 6 random colors to your rainbow palette.

[image]

Comment: The new color id are random, I need then to be from the bottom up like the flag.

Comment: Sorry @NitzanMatan I honestly do not understand your comment. Could you expound it a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, in your answer you made 6 colored id, They are scattered randomly. In group 1 there are row both in Africa and the U.S. I need that Russia and Canada will be one color, U.S and Europe and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Aah, color bands like the flag? Gotcha! Thanks @NitzanMatan for clarification.